# Login with retrofit in android

Tags: android, json, post, retrofit, postman

I am trying to use  login api via `retrofit`. I need to send only mobile number. When i am using `postman` body it is getting an output. but when iam calling with android its getting an error json like below

```
{
"error": "Validation error",
"error_code": "001",
"Validation_errors": {
    "mobile": "<p>The Mobile field is required.</p>"
}
}
```

HomeActivity.class

```
 ApiInterface apiService =
                                ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
                        Map<String,String> user = new HashMap<>();
                        user.put("mobile",username.getText().toString().trim());

                        Call<ResponseBody> mService = apiService.loginwithno(user);
                        Log.d("TAG", "response: " + mService.toString());
                        mService.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                    try {
                                        String result = response.body().string();
                                        JSONObject mJsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                                        Log.d("TAG", "response: " + mJsonObject.toString());

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    buttonVisible();
                                    username.setError("Please try again");
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                                call.cancel();
                                buttonVisible();
                                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(buttonLogin,
                                        "Please check your internet connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                                snackbar.show();

                            }
```

ApiClient

```
public class ApiClient {
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://nast.in/driverpool/api/index.php/";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient() {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

ApiInterface

```
public interface ApiInterface {


@POST("account/login?")
Call<ResponseBody> loginwithno(@Body Map<String, String> mobile);

@POST("account/verifyotp")
Call<ResponseBody> verifyotp(@Body HashMap<String, String> mobile);//Param name: mobile, otp

@POST("account/resendotp")
Call<ResponseBody> resentotp(@Body HashMap<String, String> mobile);
}
```

Postman screenshot
[image]

Comment: username is it mean phonenumber user.put("mobile",username.getText().toString().trim());??try to locat the request and ensure that its json format and not null and its in the same length that api should accept @Arya

Comment: response is not getting any value.its getting null data

Answer (score 0):

First you don't need '?' in your api and i think you must send json in your @body so create class like this

```
public class SendLoginData{
    @SerializedName("mobile")
    public String mobile;

    public SendLoginData(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }
}
```

And use it in ApiInterface

```
@POST("account/login")
Call<ResponseBody> loginwithno(@Body SendLoginData post);
```

Comment: Now `iam getting java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String okhttp3.ResponseBody.string()' on a null object reference` error

Comment: try to debug response in your code . see response.raw

Comment: response is not getting any value.its getting null data

Answer (score 0):

You need to make few changes in code.

- Change your login api to receive json like this, include gson library if you have not added in project.

  ```
  @POST("account/login?")
  Call loginwithno(@Body Map mobile);
  ```
- Create an ApiErrorResponse object to handle your api error. Add getter, setter and  @SerializedName as required.

  ```
   class ApiErrorResponse{
      String error;
      String error_code;
      ValidationErrors Validation_errors; 
   } 
   class ValidationErrors{
      String mobile;
   }
  ```
- on API error handle like this

  ```
     if(!response.isSuccessful()){
          Converter converter =
                  ApiClient.getClient().responseBodyConverter(ApiErrorResponse.class, new Annotation[0]);
          ApiErrorResponse errors = null;
          try {
              errors = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
          } catch (Exception e) {
  ```

  ```
      }
      if(errors!=null){
       //Handle your API Error logic here
      }
  ```

  }

Comment: I have tried this one.but it is returning null value

Comment: Need little more data to find the issue, is it NullPointerException or null?   if "null" What value you are getting as null? can you post your response format and status code that you have got?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: On which statement, it seems your response is null, can you confirm? If response is not null, let me know which statement is causing this issue.

Comment: it is not enter in to     if (response.isSuccessful()) {}

Comment: When i try to log ` Log.d("TAG", "response: " + response.isSuccessful());` it is returning false

Comment: In my code snippet, I have put negation before response.isSuccessful(). "!response.isSuccessful()".  Just put negation before it and try. Post in comment if you still face the issue.